# Animated elevated button on Z Axis on working in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am new to flutter animation where I am trying to animate my button repeatedly in z-axis to give an impression that this button is already clicked i.e. When the screen opens, it is already going on with animation.

Below is my code:

```
class AnimatedElevationButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedElevationButton({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnimatedElevationButton> createState() =>
      _AnimatedElevationButtonState();
}

class _AnimatedElevationButtonState extends State<AnimatedElevationButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        lowerBound: 0.8,
        upperBound: 1.2,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1));

    _controller.repeat(reverse: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String name = "Rishabh Chauhan";
    bool isSelectedUser = true;
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(isSelectedUser
                ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8)
                : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3)),
          ),
          child: Text(
            name,
            maxLines: 2,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
        builder: (context, widget) =>
            Transform.scale(scale: _controller.value, child: widget),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It is getting the exception.

> Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

Comment: This is probably happening when you are trying to revisit the page. Have you tried calling     _controller.dispose(); before super.dispose(); in the dispose function?